# django-admin.py startproject testprj : Creates empty folder

Tags: python, django

I am new to django. I know it is silly question but i am stucked with this for so long. I run the command to create a django project using the command 'django-admin.py startproject testprj'. I creates a folder named testprj but nothing created inside the folder.

It shows no error in the command prompt. where i made the mistake ?

When i tried to run the downloaded prject it showing the following error

```
D:\ \tracker\tracker>python manage.py runserver
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init
338, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init
330, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.p
 in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\comman
py", line 50, in execute
    super(Command, self).execute(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.p
 in execute
    translation.activate('en-us')
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\utils\translation\__in
e 146, in activate
    return _trans.activate(language)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\utils\translation\tran
ine 219, in activate
    _active.value = translation(language)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\utils\translation\tran
ine 205, in translation
    _translations[language] = DjangoTranslation(language)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\utils\translation\tran
ine 114, in __init__
    self._init_translation_catalog()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\utils\translation\tran
ine 151, in _init_translation_catalog
    translation = self._new_gnu_trans(localedir, use_null_fallback)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\utils\translation\tran
ine 135, in _new_gnu_trans
    fallback=use_null_fallback)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\gettext.py", line 469, in translation
    raise IOError(ENOENT, 'No translation file found for domain', d
IOError: [Errno 2] No translation file found for domain: u'django'
```

Can anyone help me to solve and explain why this happening ?? 
thanks in advance.

Comment: check if you have installed django correctly by typing python and then >>> import django
>>> print(django.get_version())

Comment: I think you don't have to create a folder first. Django will create it for you. Delete it and try again.

Comment: I didnt created the folder. the command creates folder only and nothing else created for the project..

and 
>>> import django
>>> print(django.get_version())
1.8
@Aameer

Comment: any reason you're using the in development version of django? You should be using django 1.7, it's the latest release

Comment: @VivekAnanthan as mentioned above that you are using development version try shifting to django 1.7 follow the docs here (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/intro/install/)